# Android RuntimeException Gson Parsing Exception: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader()

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, gson

I am trying to pass `ArrayList of Intent` objects in `SharedPreferences`. For that, I am using `gson` to convert `ArrayList of Intents` to `String` and then set in the shared preferences. Setting shared preferences is being dones successfully but on retrieving i am receiving the following exception:

### Exception

```
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary/com.tzoomers.birthdaysdiary.NotificationView}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader() with no args
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke protected java.lang.ClassLoader() with no args
07-06 00:50:05.712: E/AndroidRuntime(22674):    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$2.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:94)
```

### Setting SharedPreferences

```
ArrayList<Intent> notificationIntent = new ArrayList<Intent>();

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
String connectionsJSONString = new Gson().toJson(notificationIntent);
editor.putString("intents", connectionsJSONString);
editor.commit();
```

### Retriving from SharedPreference

```
String connectionsJSONString = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
                                        .getString("intents", null);
Type type = new TypeToken < ArrayList < Intent >> () {}.getType();
notificationsIntent = new Gson().fromJson(connectionsJSONString, type);
```

Can anyone please help me out how can i achieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I changed my implementation for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this issue was to create my own object with the necessary data. It saves space and fixes this issue. The issue arises when you try to serialize android objects.